# Sed error with directory

Tags: linux, bash, replace, sed, directory

I'm trying to use sed to replace some directories over a file. This is how I'm using the sed to replace. 
`sed -i "s/location_apache/$CUSTOM_INSTALL_HOME/g" $apache_boing`
Now, the problem comes with the `$CUSTOM_INSTALL_HOME` variable. Because is a directory.
Every time I tried to run the script I got this error.
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown option to `s'
I know this is because the missing \ on the `$CUSTOM_INSTALL_HOME` variable
There is any workaround for this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$CUSTOM_INSTALL_HOME` has forward slash `/` you can use a different delimiter like hash `#` in sed:

```
sed -i "s#location_apache#$CUSTOM_INSTALL_HOME#g" $apache_boing
```